# printf not working and other troubles

Tags: c, printf, cs50, printf-debugging

I finally got my change program to print out some numbers instead of throwing a floating point exception. However, now it is slightly off. Instead of giving 2 quarters, 1 dime, 1 nickel, and 2 pennies, the program only selects one penny and I cannot figure out why from any inspection on the conditionals or structure of the code. I added some checks in each if statement but not even that is printing out, I am incredibly confused now..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int changeF(float change, float  div)
{
    int c = change/div;
    return c;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("Enter the bill amount:");
    float bill = GetFloat();
    printf("Enter the payment amount:");
    float payment = GetFloat();
    float q = .25; float di = .1; float n = .05; float p = .01;
    float change = payment - bill;
    do
    {
        if (bill >= 0.0 && payment >= 0.0 && change >= 0.0)
        {
            if (change >= q)
            {
                int quarters = changeF(change, q);
                printf("%d quarters\n", quarters);
                change = change - (.25*quarters);
            }
            if (change >= di)
            {
                int dimes = changeF(change, di);
                printf("%d dimes\n", dimes);
                change = change - (.1*dimes);
            }
            if (change >= n)
            {   
                int nickels = changeF(change, n);
                printf("%d nickels\n", nickels);
                change = change - (.05*nickels);
                printf("%f change", change);
            }
            if (change >= p)
            {
                int pennies = changeF(change, p);
                printf("%d pennies\n", pennies);
                change = change - (.01*pennies);
                printf("%f", change);
            }
        }
    }
    while (change > 0.0);
}
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`). Then **use a debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: add in some trace showing what bill, payment and change are before the if (bill >= 0.0)

Please not that all your floating point numbers should have 'f' after them. 0.0 is interpreted as 0.0d and then has to be downconverted to a float, which might result in strangeness. Not in this case, certainly, but it's a good habit to get into when dealing with floats

Answer (score 3):

Try again by appending a newline at the end of the string:

```
printf("Enter the bill amount:\n");
```

Reason: `stdout` is line buffered, and you'll need to give it a newline to flush the output.

Or explicitly flush it by `fflush(stdout);`.

Comment: This does not seem to be related to the problem described.

Answer (score 2):

Don't think in terms of dollars, but in terms of cents and use integer arithmetic for your calculations. You can still have the user enter a dollar amount by rounding:

```
int bill = GetFloat() * 100 + 0.5;
```

The constants for the values will then of course also be integers, namely 25, 10, 5, and 1.

Then your `changeF` function is just an integer division. (You can forgo the division by one for the pennies - just make the rest of the change pennies.)

You don't even need the `do`... `while` loop. It is enough to do the calculation just once. Look for quarters, dimes and nickels and the rest is pennies. Done. No need to re-iterate.